# Laravel language settings per user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I know how to set default language in application by using App::setLocale('es');

I'm thinking about setting individual language per user after an user logs in.

Currently, the only way I have in mind is to set a general language and use variable inside a Lang::get() command:

```
$user_language = 'gr';

Lang::get('messages.welcome'.$user_language);
```

Is there any other way of setting language setting per user?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not just use `App::setLocale()` to set the language according to the user preferences if the user is logged in. According to the [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/localization#language-files):

> You may change the active language at any time using the `App::setLocale` method.

So you could do that maybe like this:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    // If user is logged in
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        // Get the user specific language
        $lang = Auth::user()->language;

        // Set the language
        App::setLocale($lang);
    }
});
```

Comment: Because this way, global language settings for the whole application would be set, not per user. Two logged users at the same time, with different language preferences is what we need to achieve.

Comment: But your language is set on each request based on the logged in user's language preferences, that's why it's being set in `App::before()`. Each login session is separate. This does not set the language for all sessions, just for the current one. So each user will get the language in their preferences.

Comment: I didn't know that language settings are being set per session, I thought it gets set globally.

Comment: I just checked it by setting this filter + db table colon and by loggind at the same time using two different browsers. And it seems to work, these two users have two different language settings and after loggin in both of them at the sam time, messages in different languages are being shown as desired.

Comment: Yes. Everytime a new user requests a page from your app a new session gets created, which is unique to that user. That session expires after a period of inactivity based on the `lifetime` setting in `app/config/session.php`.

Comment: I hope that choosing "Remember me" during login will make this individual language prefference permanent until a user logs out.

Comment: You just need to store the language setting for each user in the database and the rest is done autmatically by the method in my answer. Even if a user logs out, the moment he logs in again that method will automatically set the language preferences for him. The "Remember me" option doesn't affect this at all.

Comment: @MathieuB Beginning with Laravel 5, the application `before` and `after` filters have been removed. For newer versions on Laravel (including 8), you should use a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware) instead of `App:before`.